# Defining dependent Django Model Fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have to define a model where one of the fields depends on the other.

I am storing commodity trades, and the grades of the commodities vary based on the kind of commodity. For example if I store a coal and an iron trade I need to specify what is the quantity of each grade being traded.

```
Example:

{'Grade–I':500, 'Grade-II':1000, 'Washery-Grade-I':0, 'Washery-Grade-II':0, 'Washery-Grade-III':100}

{'Fe 65%+':10, 'Fe 60-65%':55,'Fe 55-60%':0}
```

One possible approach is storing the commodity type as a CharField with choices and serializing the the grade quantity and storing it as a JSONField.

```
 class TradeRetail (models.Model):
        commodity_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=(('CO','COAL'),('IO','IRON-ORE'),('WTI','WTI'),), blank=False)
        grade_quantity = JSONField()
```

My questions are:

a) Is this the neatest way to create a Model?

b) How do I define the relationships between grade_quantity and commodity_type to generate appropriate forms to obtain user inputs?

c) Will all the custom validations I write sit in the clean() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get correctly your problem, I think it would more "Django-compliant" to define two models: one containing the commodity_type, and one containing the grade_quantity. Then, you can create a foreign key in commodity_type to link it with grade_quantity.
As general documentation, you may read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Exemple:

```
class Commodity (models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(...)
    quantity = models.ForeignKey('Commodity')

class Grade (models.Model):
    type = models.<your type adapted to the grade quantity field>
```

Warning: I haven't test this exact example, but it looks like what you're trying to achieve. Have a look at the page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

For your questions:

a) For tips on how to create models, see the first links with OneToOne examples. Usually, it is useful to add a **str**(self) function for displaying correctly the name of the model instance. Read carefully the examples in Django documentation to have tips about how to correctly write your model (usually you define first the fields, then the methods of the models, and often the **str** method).

b) The ForeignKey field is the link between two models (oneToOne). A ManyToMany link exists also with the ManyToManyField field (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

c) Normally: yes. The example I propose may need you to write on a different way the validation you already developed.

Comment: Thanks I am following an approach quite similar to the one proposed by you here.